# ”Need to” and ”Would need to”

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness

What is the difference between the following sentences?

(1) You/I need to do it

(2) You/I would need to do it

Do we use the second one for distancing from reality and being more polite?

Comment: (2) could occur in backshift or express modal remoteness depending on context.

Comment: You need more context to be sure. In some contexts the would is required, in some it is just a linguistic flourish that can be excluded without loss, in some it is wrong usage. We need to know what prompted the statement to give advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I need to do it."

This usage expresses *immediate necessity* - similar to "must do it" but it shows less emphasis and obligation.

> "I would need to do it."

In this example, the modal expresses a hypothetical situation such as a conditional:

> "[If something *happened*,] I *would* need..."

or can imply the *behavior* of a person, or a different temporal *view*(time of utterance).

It doesn't necessarily mean the speaker wants to be polite, though it can in a different context.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "the behaviour of a person" or  "a different temporal view"?

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences are correct.
The word **would** sounds less direct & more polite.
Besides, **would** indicates a possibility, i.e., I'm not yet certain to do something :
I would need to do it if you want. Here my decision depends on whether you want.